# Through which number we can remove the question mark?

Tags: calculation-puzzle, number-sequence

[image]

I'm trying to solve this puzzle but so much confused and can't understand even.Please help me to solve this puzzle and also explain briefly.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Another way to see it (which also includes the 10 in the rule) is:

> Diagonally (starting in top left corner): 10-13-16-19-22 (+3)
>  Diagonally (starting in top right corner): 10-8-6-4-**2** (-2)

Answer (score 18):

Simple:

> +5, -10, +15, -20. The answer is $2$.

Comment: Your pattern is, actually, the selfsame as stated in @Runemoro's answer (just a bit less complicated). If I could upvote you again to match upvotes, I would. $(+1)$ ;)

Comment: @user477343; I thought the 10 was 'puzzle number 10'!

Comment: Also the top box is -0 if you consider the 10 as the merging of two cells with 10 in it.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same answer as everyone else but used a different method. Thought I'd still share.

> 10 + 10 = 20 
>  08 + 13 = 21 
>  16 + 06 = 22 
>  04 + 19 = 23 
>  22 + ?? = 24 
>  24 - 22 = 02 
>  ? = 2

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider that the sum of the outer values in each column minus the inner equals $10$, so

> $8+22 - (16+4) =10$
> $13+? - (6+19) = 10 \Rightarrow ? = 22. $

Answer (score 1):

After reading the other answers I think I worked this out in a really convoluted way - but thought I'd share anyway:

> Comparing to 10, the smaller number decrease is 2 thirds of the larger number increase
>
> ```
>  13 = increase of  3  ->  2 thirds of  3 = 2  ->  10 - 2 = 8 
>
>  16 = increase of  6  ->  2 thirds of  6 = 4  ->  10 - 4 = 6 
>
>  19 = increase of  9  ->  2 thirds of  9 = 6  ->  10 - 6 = 4 
>
>  22 = increase of 12  ->  2 thirds of 12 = 8  ->  10 - 8 = 2 
>
>
>  Which gives the answer of 2
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Plese correct me if im wrong

> 10,
>  8-13 , 8+3 =11,
>  16-6, 6+6 =12,
>  4-19,9+4 =13,
>  22-?,12+2=14

Comment: @NavyaRavathi Hello and welcome to PSE. Please familiarise yourself with the site rules. You've added a solution to a puzzle with an accepted solution. Also your  answer is very unclear. And finally you should use spoilers to hide your answers.